# Websocket timeout with Apache Wicket and embedded Jetty

Tags: websocket, wicket, embedded-jetty

I am using Wicket with an embedded Jetty webserver. The application is using websockets, therefore the Jetty setup looks the following:

```
FilterHolder filterHolder = new FilterHolder(Jetty9WebSocketFilter.class);
filterHolder.setInitParameter("applicationClassName", "MyApplication");
filterHolder.setInitParameter("filterMappingUrlPattern", "/*");

WebAppContext context = new WebAppContext();
context.setResourceBase(".");
context.addFilter(filterHolder, "/*", null);
context.addServlet(DefaultServlet.class, "/*");

Server server = new Server(8083);
server.setHandler(context);

try {
    server.start();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Everything works fine, besides the websocket timeout. Research showed that Jetty's websocket connections time out, although this is not common for webservers.

After researching I stumbled upon the following init parameter, that I now pass to my `filterHolder`:

```
filterHolder.setInitParameter("maxIdleTime", "5000");
```

And apparently this parameter does something - because now the timeout occurs notably faster than before, exactly after 5 seconds.

But I couldn't figure out how I can disable the timeout completely. Using `-1`, `0` or even `Integer.MIN_VALUE` instead of `5000` does nothing, there is still a timeout after a while. The documentation I found says nothing about an according value.

What init parameter can I use to disable the websocket timeout? Or do I have to stick with setting the timeout to some ridiculously high value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jetty 9.1 has its own [`WebSocketUpgradeFilter`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/server/WebSocketUpgradeFilter.html), use that one, and then modify the default policy's idle timeout.

Example:

```java
package jetty.websocket;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.OnWebSocketMessage;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.WebSocket;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.WebSocketUpgradeFilter;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.server.pathmap.ServletPathSpec;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.ServletUpgradeRequest;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.ServletUpgradeResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketCreator;

public class JettyWebSocketViaFilter
{
    @WebSocket
    public static class EchoSocket
    {
        @OnWebSocketMessage
        public void onMessage(Session session, String msg)
        {
            session.getRemote().sendStringByFuture(msg);
        }
    }

    public static class EchoCreator implements WebSocketCreator
    {
        private EchoSocket echoer = new EchoSocket();

        @Override
        public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req, ServletUpgradeResponse resp)
        {
            return echoer;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Server server = new Server();
        ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        connector.setPort(8080);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        // Setup the basic application "context" for this application at "/"
        // This is also known as the handler tree (in jetty speak)
        ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler(ServletContextHandler.SESSIONS);
        context.setContextPath("/");
        server.setHandler(context);

        // Add the websocket filter
        WebSocketUpgradeFilter wsfilter = WebSocketUpgradeFilter.configureContext(context);
        wsfilter.getFactory().getPolicy().setIdleTimeout(5000);
        wsfilter.addMapping(new ServletPathSpec("/"),new EchoCreator());

        // The filesystem paths we will map
        String staticRoot = "src/main/webapp/websocket/protocol";

        ServletHolder holderDefault = new ServletHolder("default",DefaultServlet.class);
        holderDefault.setInitParameter("resourceBase",staticRoot);
        holderDefault.setInitParameter("dirAllowed","true");
        context.addServlet(holderDefault,"/");

        try
        {
            server.start();
            server.join();
        }
        catch (Throwable t)
        {
            t.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

**Timeouts in Jetty with WebSockets:**

Since WebSocket is an upgraded HTTP/1.1 request you have essentially 2 timeouts to worry about.

First is the connector idle timeout, that will be used for the HTTP/1.1 initial portion of the incoming Upgrade request.  This is configured at the server level, with the connector that it has.  With Jetty, any value 0 or below is considered an infinite timeout.

Next, you have the websocket endpoint specific idle timeout. If it has a value greater than 0, then it is applied to already established connection's idle timeout (the one from the server side).

Some combinations and what it means ...

```
Server Connector IdleTimeout  | WebSocket Endpoint IdleTimeout | Actual Timeout
------------------------------+--------------------------------+----------------
   30,000 ms                  |       -1                       |   30,000 ms
   30,000 ms                  |   10,000 ms                    |   10,000 ms
   30,000 ms                  |  400,000 ms                    |  400,000 ms
  500,000 ms                  |       -1                       |  500,000 ms
  500,000 ms                  |      200 ms                    |      200 ms
       -1                     |       -1                       |  (infinite)
       -1                     |    1,000 ms                    |    1,000 ms
```

You can think of the Server Connector IdleTimeout as a TCP level timeout, while the WebSocket endpoint timeout is an application level idle timeout.

Hope this helps.

Comment: went ahead and let Wicket know about this filter ... https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5453

Comment: I used your code, including classes `EchoSocket` and `EchoCreator` but my wicket application is not knowing about the opened web socket connection now. I have a `WebSocketBehavior` on my current wicket pages that previously got notified when a websocket connection was opened. Now the `createWebSocket` method of `EchoCreator` is called but wicket gets not notified anymore.

Comment: On an additional note, my original question is still unanswered. The documentation of `WebSocketPolicy` provides no hint on what value to use for "no timeout at all". I think if I could figure out that value I wouldn't even need to change my code because I can use the init parameter - I just don't know what value to pass.

Comment: Added more to answer about idle timeouts

Comment: In the end `connector.setIdleTimeout(-1);` was the one line that was missing, I can still use `Jetty9WebSocketFilter` and use the line I specified in my question to set the client timeout. Thanks for clarification.